# how to convert array of objects to one object i can obj.find() in

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I use GSAP plugin that takes array of objects i can apply css animation to. It looks like this:

```
animation.To([object1, object2, object3], time, { opacity: 0 })
```

object1 may be a jquery object made within element selector ie:

```
var object1 = $('div');
```

I made a function that selects elements to object1:

```
var obj = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < object1.length; i++ ) {
  if ( object1[i].attr('id') != "abc" ) {
     obj.push(object1[i]);
  }
}
```

After it is done i have an array of objects from object1 that id is not abc. However i need to to animate simultanaously three couples of objects:

```
obj
obj.find('.xxx')
obj.find('.yyy')
```

However, because obj is not a jquery object (like object1 is before filtering) i can not apply find function to it. How can i convert obj from array of objects to real jquery object of objects?

Comment: To make it a jquery object, it should be enough to say `obj.push($(object1[i])) ` instead of `obj.push(object1[i])`;

so, apart from that.. you talk about filtering. where is your filter-function? or do you mean filtering by "not abc"? Seems somewhat unclear to me. tbh i don't really get what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is this:

> After it is done i have an array of objects from object1 that id is
>   not `abc`.

It's better to use

```
var object1 = $('div[id != "abc"]');
```

So that you don't need the for loop and you can directly use `object1` which is JQuery object